# How to implement a console command line for tomcat web application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web

I have a web application

- hosted by tomcat 7.1
- using spring 3.1 mvc framework.

I want to implement a command line function for tomcat console window, to read commands and perform some action or output some information to console. How can I do it?

Example:
type "**show memory**", then display JVM memory information to console.

Can I do it just by `System.in`? Will there be any thread-safe problem?

Comment: you can use the directory C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin if you want !

Comment: Then..... where does spring mvc framework come into picture. elaborate your question

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your need correctly, but you could set up a simple REST API for that and use console tools to communicate with that.

Comment: you can just use JConsole to look at the memory and other JVM info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running as a web application in Tomcat, you won't get any access to System.in or the console: Tomcat is typically started in the background, detached from all consoles. And it won't provide you witn meaningful access to the console.

The way to go is to either provide a REST API as suggested by @rlegendi in the comments (any other API would work as well) and write a separate command line application that interfaces with your API. Alternatively utilize the "manager" interface - if I remember correctly from ancient past, tomcat's manager application also has some usable methods to access from external scripts.

Make sure to make those calls authenticated - at least validate that they're coming from localhost so that you simulate some kind of security in the API. Don't trust random calls coming in from the world.